Why does removing a language removes body content from nodes in this language?
I have a node in a certain language but I have deleted this language in /admin/config/regional/language and the node body content was removed along with it.
I was expecting that there would be a fallback to English (existing) or to the website's default language and the node body content would not be removed, or just won't be removed anyway (complete separation between HTML and how it is rendered).
I could reverse the situation by bringing back the deleted language and flushing all caches, then the node body content came back to appear normally, but I still want to ask to better understand how Drupal works:
Why does removing a language removes body content from nodes in this language?

It’s certainly because of a bug. It could be Node content lost after removing initial language or one of the related bugs. There is not much else to be said as an answer. It’s just bugs.
